# Deserialize Object from String with StringReader

Tags: vb.net, string, serialization

I am currently able to Serialize an object and store the data in a database by using the following code:

```
Dim x As New XmlSerializer(myObject.GetType)
Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter()
x.Serialize(sw, MyObject)
'Write sw to database
```

I can't figure out how to Deserialize the data from the database into the object.

I've tried using the reverse with no success. (The problem with the code below is that the strReader is null:)

```
Dim x As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(myObject))
Dim strReader As New StringReader(dr("xml_data") & "")
Dim tmpData As myObject = CType(x.Deserialize(strReader), myObject)
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I figured out with this problem that the Reader remains null even after you have Instantiated it. The actual error was with the Object.

Answer (score -2):

Refer to follow MS KB article that talks about serialization and deserialization.([KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730)).

You code should be fine as per the code. But, sharing the code of your object help in identification other possible issues.

Comment: I've tried to follow that article, however the article does the serialization from a text file. I need to be able to do the serialization to/from a string.